# Typeahead on dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" name="brand[]" class="form-control auto-brand" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input.auto-brand').each(function () {
            $(this).typeahead({
                name: 'brand[]',
                remote: '...'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would like that as I add the new inputs the typeahead is also initialized